# How to Extend EventTarget and CustomEvent with CUutom Details Object in Typescript 4.7

Tags: typescript, dom, types, extends, custom-events

It took me hours to figure this out, especially as most answers I found related to older Versions of typescript, or only provided part of a solution, I'd thought I share what I found and hope it helps someone.

```
class emitter extends EventTarget {
    private _myEvent: MyChoiceEvent = new MyChoiceEvent('shout', { detail: { content: 'whatever', changeType: 'added', isfromSelection: false } });
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    public dispatch = () => {
        this.dispatchEvent(this._myEvent);
    }
}

class MyChoiceEvent extends CustomEvent<MyChoiceEventDetail> {

    protected init: MyChoiceEventInit

    constructor(typeName: string, init: MyChoiceEventInit) {
        super(typeName, init);
        this.init = init
    }
}

interface MyChoiceEventInit extends CustomEventInit<MyChoiceEventDetail> {
    bubbles?: boolean;
    cancelable?: boolean;
    composed?: boolean;
    detail: MyChoiceEventDetail
}

interface MyChoiceEventDetail {
    content: string;
    changeType: 'added' | 'deleted';
    isfromSelection: boolean
}

// Test code for TS-Playground
var emmi: emitter = new emitter();
emmi.addEventListener('shout', (e: CustomEventInit) => { console.log('log: ' + e.detail.content) }, false);

window.setTimeout(emmi.dispatch, 500);
```

I guess it looks rather straight forward this way, but as a lot of this wasn't possible for quite a while most answers one can find today aren't helpful if one is looking for a straight way.